# Php Making the link path not showing all information

Tags: php

if let said this is the link for my website to link to the **index page**
**https://xxx.abc.asia**
then is it possible to make it link to "**AboutUs Page**" like
**https://xxx.abc.asia/AboutUs**
instead of using
**https://xxx.abc.asia/includes/pages/AboutUs.php**

Comment: This can be done with a .htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would need to create the .htaccess file this guide show you how to do that --> https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/
After you have that setup you need to add this to the file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```